# Eager loading mobility translations on a model collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobility

I have a simple problem with the mobility gem. I have a simple relation in my models. Let's say Company has many Employees, and Employees have a translated attribute `:job_function` that uses `backend: :table`.

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    extend Mobility

    translates :job_function, type: :string, locale_accessors: true, backend: :table
end
```

If I try to do:

```rb
Company.first.employees.map(&:job_function)
```

I get the *n+1* problem. Each of the :job_function translations is loaded individually.

How do I tell Mobility to eager load them all in one go before I start mapping over the collection?

I could not find any example of this in the documentation...

Comment: I believe you can do: `Company.first.employees.pluck(:job_function)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `pluck`, which is supported by Mobility:

```
Company.first.employees.i18n.pluck(:job_function)
```

Comment: i tried but the `pluck` return nil

Comment: but `Company.first.employees.i18n.pluck(:job_function)` work. you missed `i18n`

Comment: Thanks! That's correct, updated the answer.

Comment: Salzberge, did you have any simple solution in case we want to pre-load  employees with their translations (and avoid N+1)?, i mean maybe the OP not only query the translation job_functions but also need to do something with employees, the pluck will not allow to load employees.

Answer (score -1):

You could `includes` employees + theirs job_function translation, it's [n+2 query](https://www.rootstrap.com/blog/rails-n-2-queries/)

here's my demo, with Product model contains many Versions model which has been set up mobility for the name attribute, those corresponding to your Company, Employee, job_function respectively.

```rb
class Version < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  extend Mobility
  translates :name, locale_accessors: [:en, :ja], backend: :table
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :versions

 has_many :translation_versions, -> { 
   i18n{name.not_eq(nil)}
   .select("versions.*, 
            version_translations_#{Mobility.locale}.name AS translate_name")
  }, class_name: "Version"
end
```

With default locale `:en`

```rb
Product.includes(:translation_versions).first.translation_versions
   .map(&:translate_name)

# SELECT "products".* FROM "products" ...
# SELECT versions.*, version_translations_en.name AS translate_name 
#  FROM "versions" LEFT OUTER JOIN "version_translations" "version_translations_en" 
#  ON "version_translations_en"."version_id" = "versions"."id" 
#  AND "version_translations_en"."locale" = 'en' 
#  WHERE "version_translations_en"."name" IS NOT NULL AND "versions"."product_id" = ? ...

# => ["v1", "v2"]
```

With locale `:ja`

```rb
Mobility.locale = :ja
Product.includes(:translation_versions).first.translation_versions
   .map(&:translate_name)
# ...
# => ["ja v1", "ja v2"]
```

So just one query.

In case your `backend` setting is KeyValue, the translation tables separate not only `locale` but also the `type` (String, Text, ...), but you already decide which type for the attribute, right ? for example: name:string. So that you still only need to setup dynamic locale.

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :translation_versions, -> { 
  i18n{name.not_eq(nil)}
   .select("versions.*, 
     Version_name_#{Mobility.locale}_string_translations.value AS translate_name")
  }, class_name: "Version"
end
```

the query is same as above.

Of course, you could make `translation_versions` more generally by separate it into
a module, replace `Version` by class name, `name` by the target attribute and make a dynamic function something like `translation_#{table_name}`.