# Eager loading model instances using single SQL statement with Mobility table backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading, mobility

Using Rails 7 and [Mobility](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) 1.2.9:

```rb
# config/initializers/mobility.rb
Mobility.configure do |config|
  config.plugins do
    backend :table
    active_record
    reader
    writer
    backend_reader
    query
    cache
    dirty
    presence
  end
end

# app/models/content.rb
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  translates :slug, :title
end
```

How to find contents by slug, instantiate them into `Content` objects and query their translated attributes using one single SQL statement (for an unchanging locale)? The examples below with and without eager_loading run 2 SQL statements.

```sql
> content = Content.i18n.find_by(slug: "foo")
  Content Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "contents".* FROM "contents" INNER JOIN "content_translations" "content_translations_en" ON "content_translations_en"."content_id" = "contents"."id" AND "content_translations_en"."locale" = 'en' WHERE "content_translations_en"."slug" = 'foo' LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
> content.title
  Content::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "content_translations".* FROM "content_translations" WHERE "content_translations"."content_id" = $1  [["content_id", "..."]]
```

```sql
> content = Content.i18n.eager_load(:translations).find_by(slug: "foo")
  SQL (0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "contents"."id" FROM "contents" LEFT OUTER JOIN "content_translations" ON "content_translations"."content_id" = "contents"."id" INNER JOIN "content_translations" "content_translations_en" ON "content_translations_en"."content_id" = "contents"."id" AND "content_translations_en"."locale" = 'en' WHERE "content_translations_en"."slug" = 'blog-1-en' LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  SELECT "contents"."id" AS t0_r0, "contents"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "contents"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, ..., "content_translations"."id" AS t1_r0, "content_translations"."locale" AS t1_r1, "content_translations"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "content_translations"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "content_translations"."slug" AS t1_r4, "content_translations"."title" AS t1_r5, "content_translations"."content_id" AS t1_r6 FROM "contents" LEFT OUTER JOIN "content_translations" ON "content_translations"."content_id" = "contents"."id" INNER JOIN "content_translations" "content_translations_en" ON "content_translations_en"."content_id" = "contents"."id" AND "content_translations_en"."locale" = 'en' WHERE "content_translations_en"."slug" = 'blog-1-en' AND "contents"."id" = $1  [["id", "..."]]
> content.title
# no DB statement, but there were 2 statements at instantiation
```

NB: I do not want to [pluck attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69326922/4623987) but instead to create model instances.

Comment: Why do you even try to eager load translations when they are already loaded in the same query with join?

Comment: I don't understand, @DieterPisarewski could you please explain what is the solution you suggest? The code above shows that when eager loading is not used, two queries are executed (`Content Load` then `Content::Translation Load`).